# Naming external files using Latex \label?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am writing a latex document with theorems followed by examples. Some examples reference external Matlab scripts. I am currently implementing the reference by giving the Matlab script some name and then I insert this name into my latex document. For example,

**Example 1:** In the Matlab script *name_of_the_matlab_script.m* we validate the formula in \autoref{theorem1}.

This referencing works OK if I want to find a Matlab script given a theorem but is more cumbersome when I want to find the theorem corresponding to a given Matlab script.

I am wondering if it is possible to make Latex give external files a name depending on a \label. Continuing the example, instead of the file being called *name_of_the_matlab_script.m* it could be called *\autoref{theorem1}_name_of_the_matlab_script.m*

Comment: why not simply use the filename as the label `\label{name_of_the_matlab_script}` a label with a number such as `theorem1` should normally be avoided anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [**zref**](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref)-package you can introduce referencing-properties by means of which you can use a filename as an alias for a referencing-label and vice versa a referencing-label as an alias for a filename.

In the example below the macro `\labelAssignedToFilename` is introduced which both places the referencing-label and creates the aliases.

The macro `\labelnametofilename` can be used in situations where you wish to obtain the filename associated to a referencing-label.

The macro `\filenametolabelname` can be used in situations where you wish to obtain the referencing-label associated to a filename..

Be aware that I implemented the treatment of filenames via `\detokenize`, which is rather sloppy: `\detokenize` doubles hashes.

Besides this treating filenames with unbalanced curly braces or with consecutive spaces might also be a problem.

To do filename-handling properly, you may need a mechanism which lets you read and write arguments/filenames under verbatim-catcode-régime, keeping the delimiting verbatim-character(s) when writing to .aux-file for reading back verbatimized from there, using the same delimiters. (Currently xparse with its nice v/+v-argument types does not let you keep the delimiting verbatim-character(s)...)

Such a mechanism in turn cannot easily be brought in line with the zref-mechanism—you'd need to implement your own prallel cross-referencing-infrastructure for crossreferencing verbatimized arguments.

This is feasible but it is a bunch of code. I will do this only if it is really needed. ;-)

As a starting-point, here is the quick-and-dirty-approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref, zref}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{filename}[\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}]{}
\zref@newprop{labelname}[]{}
\newcommand\labelAssignedToFilename[2]{%
  \@bsphack
  \zref@setcurrent{labelname}{#1}%
  \zref@setcurrent{filename}{\string\detokenize{#2}}%
  \@esphack
  \ifhmode\nobreak\hskip-\@savsk\nobreak\hskip\@savsk\fi
  \label{#1}%
  \ifhmode\nobreak\hskip-\@savsk\nobreak\hskip\@savsk\fi
  \zref@labelbyprops{labelname@#2}{labelname}%
  \ifhmode\nobreak\hskip-\@savsk\nobreak\hskip\@savsk\fi
  \zref@labelbyprops{filename@#1}{filename}%
}%
\newcommand\labelnametofilename[1]{%
  \zref@refused{filename@#1}%
  \zref@extract{filename@#1}{filename}%
}%
\newcommand\filenametolabelname[1]{%
  \zref@extract{labelname@#1}{labelname}%
}%
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\labelAssignedToFilename{Thm1}{matlab_script_A.m}
If anything just cannot go wrong, it will anyway.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\labelAssignedToFilename{Thm2}{matlab_script_B.m}
Being paranoid doesn't mean they are not after you.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\labelAssignedToFilename{Thm3}{matlab_script_C.m}
Experience varies directly with equipment ruined.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\labelAssignedToFilename{Thm4}{matlab_script_D.m}
When working toward the solution of a problem, it always helps if you know the answer.
\end{theorem}

\ref{Thm1}=\ref{\filenametolabelname{matlab_script_A.m}}

\ref{Thm2}=\ref{\filenametolabelname{matlab_script_B.m}}

\ref{Thm3}=\ref{\filenametolabelname{matlab_script_C.m}}

\ref{Thm4}=\ref{\filenametolabelname{matlab_script_D.m}}

\texttt{\labelnametofilename{Thm1}}

\texttt{\labelnametofilename{Thm2}}

\texttt{\labelnametofilename{Thm3}}

\texttt{\labelnametofilename{Thm4}}

\end{document}
```

[image]